# Why does an input element increase the width of a flex container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am using `flex-box` in my demo project. when I create `flex-container`.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="flex">
<div class="form-control flex-1 flex align-item-baseline"> </div>
<div class="form-control flex-1 flex align-item-baseline"></div>
<div class="form-control flex-1 flex align-item-baseline"></div>
<div class="form-control flex-1 flex align-item-baseline"></div>
<div class="form-control flex-1 flex align-item-baseline"></div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

all `divs` have `140` **width**.
but when I insert `input field` it's width increase to `160`

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="form-control flex-1 flex align-item-baseline">
            <label class="color-red">Passport Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="min-width-0 flex-1">
        </div>
<div class="form-control flex-1 flex align-item-baseline"></div>
<div class="form-control flex-1 flex align-item-baseline"></div>
<div class="form-control flex-1 flex align-item-baseline"></div>
<div class="form-control flex-1 flex align-item-baseline"></div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

why ?

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/PKbJ9AvvVPrnw9XxnQwv?p=preview

any update ? only140px

Comment: Because `input` elements have a default minimum width set by the browser. Add `min-width: 0` to your *flex items*. (You have it added to the `input` element only.)

Comment: is it possible to `create` `constant` `width`

Comment: Yes. Define the width, and set flex items to `flex-shrink: 0` so they cannot shrink.

Comment: mean how to make constant width of container of 140 having `label` and `input`

Comment: please share the jsbin link

Comment: see not working https://plnkr.co/edit/v6PQFpZaJSidepOmfCr7?p=preview

Comment: created `t` class and added in element still `160` width

Comment: i need container always have 140px

Comment: `.t { flex: 0 0 140px; min-width: 0 }`  (apply `.t` class to flex items; remove it from `input`)...https://plnkr.co/edit/D4hHMa8BYJs7XY0cTcmg?p=preview